# $\text{min}\lVert A - B \rVert_F^2\ $ given $\ A\ne B$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, optimization, normed-spaces

$\lVert A - B \rVert_F^2 = \lVert A\rVert_F^2 + \lVert B\rVert_F^2 + 2\langle A,B \rangle_F$.
We know that $\text{min}\lVert A - B \rVert_F^2$ occurs when $A=B$ which implies $\lVert A\rVert_F - \lVert B\rVert_F= 0$.

Let $A\ne B$, can we obtain  $\text{min}\lVert A - B \rVert_F^2$ possibly in terms of norms $\lVert A\rVert_F$ and $\lVert B\rVert_F$? Is this feasible?

Comment: The question does not make sense in the language you have used. Which variable are you minimizing over?

Comment: If you add in the constraint that $A \neq B$, then you will no longer obtain a minimum; you'll just obtain an infimum of $0$ that cannot be attained.

Comment: Got it. $A$ is parameterized. I can handle it now. Thanks.